# $L(V,\prod_i W_i) \cong \prod_i L(V,W_i)$ & $L(\oplus W_i,V) \cong \prod_i L(W_i,V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let V be a vector space, and $\{W_i\}$ a family of vector spaces. Then prove that

a) $L(V,\prod_i W_i) \cong \prod_i L(V,W_i)$

b) $L(\oplus W_i,V) \cong \prod_i L(W_i,V)$.

---

a)Let $\ T \in L(V,\prod_i W_i)$ i.e $\ T:V \rightarrow \prod_iW_i$ is a linear transformation. Let $x \in V$ then $\ T(x)=(T_i(x))_i \in \prod_iW_i$, where each $T_i:V \rightarrow W_i$.

$T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y) \implies (T_i(x+y))_i=(T_i(x))_i+(T_i(y))_i=(T_i(x)+T_i(y))_i$ ---(1)

$T(ax)=aT(x)\implies (T_i(ax))_i=a(T_i(x))_i=(aT_i(x))_i$ [for some scalar $a$ and vector $x$] ---(2)

Hence each $T_i \in L(V,W_i)$. One has $\Phi:L(V,\prod_i W_i) \rightarrow \prod_i L(V,W_i) \ \ \text{defined as}\ \ T \mapsto (T_i)_i$.
Which can be shown as a linear transformation, by using (1) and (2). Clearly, $\Phi$ is an onto linear transformation.

$\ T \in \operatorname{Ker}\Phi \implies \Phi(T)=(O_i)_i$ [where $O_i:V \rightarrow W_i$ is the zero-transformation] $\implies (T_i)_i=(O_i)_i \implies T(x)=0 \ \  \text{for all x} \in V.$ Hence $\operatorname{Ker} \Phi = \{0\}$.

Hence $L(V,\prod_i W_i) \cong \prod_i L(V,W_i)$.

b) How do I proceed with this one?

What is a counter-example for $L(\prod W_i,V) \cong \prod_i L(W_i,V)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is very clear that for any family $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha}$ of linear maps $f_\alpha : W_\alpha \to V$ there is a unique linear map $f : \bigoplus_{\alpha} W_\alpha \to V$ such that $f \circ i_\beta = f_\beta$ for every $\beta$. Here, $i_\beta : W_\beta \to \bigoplus_{\alpha} W_\alpha$ sends $w_\beta$ to $(w_\alpha)_{\alpha}$, where $w_\alpha = 0$ if $\alpha \neq \beta$.

> Just define $f : \bigoplus_{\alpha} W_\alpha \to V$ by $(w_\alpha)_{\alpha} \mapsto \sum_{\alpha} f_\alpha(w_\alpha)$. Notice that this is well-defined since $\{\alpha : w_\alpha \neq 0\}$ is a finite set for every $(w_\alpha)_{\alpha} \in \bigoplus_{\alpha} W_\alpha$.

Thus, the rule $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha} \mapsto f$ is a one-to-one function from $\prod_{\alpha} \mathcal L(W_\alpha,V)$ onto $\mathcal L \big(\!\bigoplus_{\alpha} W_\alpha,V \big)$. Now, I will leave you to check that this is a linear map.

Comment: What is a counter-example for $L(∏_iW_i,V)≅\prod_iL(W_i,V)$?